# Can't unlock a file for path change

Tags: command-line, permissions, osx

I'm trying to order the path entries on my mac, but it seems that my `/etc/paths` file is Locked.

I tried the instructions on this [link](http://daniel.hepper.net/blog/2011/02/change-order-of-path-entries-on-mac-os-x/), but I can't save the file as it is locked. I even tried `chflags nouchg /etc/paths` but that did not work too. Can you help me with this?

Comment: What error message do you get when you try and open the file with an editor from the terminal? Also, please post the output of `ls -l  /etc/path`.

Comment: Set your `PATH` in your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @bahamat `.bashrc` is not read in OSX because for some strange reason, the default terminal starts a login shell, the file to modify is `~/.profile` instead. In any case, the OP is trying to reorder, not re-set their path and setting it in `.profile` would mean either overwriting the original, having duplicate entries or an unnecessary amount of scripting.

Comment: -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  46 Aug  3 14:04 /etc/paths this is the output i made a mistake with the q/s its paths not path